# не работает расширение mysqli на debian 9

Tags: php

Настраиваю LAMP на Debian 9, поставил apache2 + php 7( расширение php-myslqnd установил), но при попытке подключится к базе через mysqli_connect апач в логе пишет - PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysqli_connect();
Переустановка apach2 и php ничего не дала

Comment: включите расширение в конфиге

Comment: @teran, расширение включено.

Comment: `phpinfo()` гляньте тогда для проверки что оно реально загружено

Comment: @teran, хм, в phpinfo нет информации о модуле, проверил php.ini, экстеншен включен

Comment: путь к ини там указывается? убедитесь, что тот же файл смотрите.

Comment: @teran, путь верный возвращает -/etc/php/7.0/apache2/php.ini,  в этом же файле я после установки расскоментировал строку extension=pgp_mysqli.dll/